# HTML5 drop event clientX parameter is undefined in Chrome (jQuery used for event binding)

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, webkit

I'm experimenting with HTML5's Drag and Drop. I'm trying to drag an html button. On my listener of the drag and drop events, however, I can't seem to be able to access most actual event parameters. On drop event I can't seem to find the clientX parameter. When I tried to set the data of the transferData (in the listener of startdrag), it also said transferData was undefined.

I'm using jQuery for binding the events (but using native DnD) and the listener functions, like so:

```
$("[name=droppable]").bind('drop',handleDrop);
function handledrop(event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX;
}
```

Another question: the drag and drop is only working in Chrome - in Firefox it doesn't even begin to drag. What are the differences of implementation across browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the event listener $([name=droppable])[0].addEventListener('drop',handleDrop);. The event received in handleDrop now matches expectations.